# how to change 24hours dropdown list to 12hours dropdown list in jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

this is my jquery code.in this dropdown list show 24hours time format.how to change 12hours[am/pm] format list.

```
$(function() {
    $('#occasionStartTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        format : 'g:i A'
    });
    $('#occasionEndTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        format : 'g:i A'

    });
    $('#eventDatePicker').datetimepicker({
        timepicker : false,
        format : 'd.m.Y'
    });
```

[image: this is my form image it's show 24hours dropdown list,how to change 12hours[am/pm] dropdown list]

Answer (score 1):

Use `formatTime:'g:iA'`.

So your code will look something like this:

```
$('#occasionStartTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        formatTime:'g:iA'
    });
    $('#occasionEndTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        formatTime:'g:iA'

    });
    $('#eventDatePicker').datetimepicker({
        timepicker : false,
        format : 'd.m.Y'
    });
```

You can find more about this on [their documentation](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#formatTime).